# How do I copy/paste merged cells from excel via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, openpyxl

I tried using openpyxl and had a lot of trouble, now im trying pandas and an getting tons of tracebacks. Seems like copy pasting merged cells is hard and very specific, either that or im just a nooby. Can anyone help with tips or solutions?

[Heres my code with pandas](https://pastebin.com/bk2xbPNS)

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Set the paths for the interim and finals folders
interim_folder = r'C:\Users\Jake_\Downloads\Code\Interims'
finals_folder = r'C:\Users\Jake_\Downloads\Code\Finals'

# Get a list of all files in the interim folder
interim_files = os.listdir(interim_folder)

# Iterate over each file in the interim folder
for file_name in interim_files:
    # Check if the file is an Excel file
    if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
        interim_file_path = os.path.join(interim_folder, file_name)
        finals_file_path = os.path.join(finals_folder, file_name)

        # Read the interim Excel file using pandas with the xlrd engine
        interim_data = pd.read_excel(interim_file_path, sheet_name='Financial Report Interim Mar 10', engine='xlrd')

        # Copy the required data to a new DataFrame
        finals_data = pd.DataFrame()
        finals_data['Column B'] = interim_data.iloc[3:8, 1]  # Copy B4:B8
        finals_data['Column D'] = interim_data.iloc[5:201, 3]  # Copy D6:D200
        finals_data['Column E'] = interim_data.iloc[5:201, 4]  # Copy E6:E200
        finals_data['Column F'] = interim_data.iloc[5:201, 5]  # Copy F6:F200
        finals_data['Column G'] = interim_data.iloc[5:201, 6]  # Copy G6:G200

        # Write the data to the finals Excel file
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(finals_file_path, engine='openpyxl')
        finals_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Final Financial Report July 7', index=False)
        writer.save()
```

[and heres the tracebacks i get](https://pastebin.com/3AAJ7VgH)

What im trying to do: I have about 100 files in a folder called interims - and each of those files has a corresponding file thats literally the same name a folder called finals. I want to copy a specific few cells from a specific worksheet called "Financial Report Interim Mar 10" from each of the files in the interim folder and paste into a worksheet called "Final Financial Report July 7" in the corresponding files in the finals folder. Have been trying and failing for like 6 hours.

Thanks

Tried using openpyxl and now pandas, still no luck at all.

Comment: if you can, share a single Excel file, with the input and expected output

Comment: Yeah, I can when I get home - at the store right now. Ill add it in about 30 minutes!

Comment: from the error messages, you are using xlrd instead of openpyxl. pass openpyxl to the engine parameter in read_excel. That should solve your problem and probably even remove the need to share the Excel file

Comment: yes that part seems pretty clear  `interim_data = pd.read_excel(interim_file_path, sheet_name='Financial Report Interim Mar 10', engine='xlrd')` and as the traceback says `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported` XLRD supports xls files, not xlsx. Also you should be able to do this in Openpyxl only, Pandas should not be necesary but of course is your choice.

Comment: Interesting, so is there anything specific that you guys would think about changing besides just using openpyxl instead of xlrd? I had used openpyxl for a few of the first attempts and still found some random errors throughout - never could get it working. It just makes it so much harder with merge cells. Also, heres the link to a photo of the excel, I can actually upload the file if needed as well. https://imgur.com/kMeWch2

Comment: This is what I had before - using just openpyxl - https://pastebin.com/MhNGEzMD.
I end up running into this error among others when I try to change it.
https://pastebin.com/diXuF4Yp

Comment: What you want to do sounds pretty straight forward. Just remember that if there are merged cells e.g. B1 and B2 then the cell B2 does not exist anymore and trying to reference  it (in a loop) will result in an error. Any the image will help, to see what your working with but the imgur link does not work (at least for my location if its country specific).

Comment: No worries, i can upload the excel file for you. But that is very helpful, so the problem may be me trying to copy all of the cells that technically dont exist anymore? I never thought of that for some reason. Let me upload the excel really quick!

Comment: Here is the link to the excel! Any help would be amazing, been stuck on it too long lol..
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118kvvaX7a3QucfLjw3F6ri9RBlrb-Dgl/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114752780041755797336&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the excel workbook you have provided is the one being written to i.e. the 'Final' sheet, so not sure what the interim sheet looks like.
 However to address the actual issue in the Openpyxl only code from the traceback you provided;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake_\Downloads\step5.py", line 34, in <module>
    merged_range = interim_worksheet.merged_cells[cell.coordinate]
TypeError: 'MultiCellRange' object is not subscriptable
```

You want to obtain the top left cell of the merged cells. That cannot be obtained directly from merged cells, change that section

```
for cell in row:
    if cell.coordinate in interim_worksheet.merged_cells:
        merged_range = interim_worksheet.merged_cells[cell.coordinate]
        top_left_cell = merged_range.split(':')[0]
        finals_worksheet[cell.coordinate].value = interim_worksheet[top_left_cell].value
    else:
```

to something like this

```
for cell in row:
    if cell.coordinate in interim_worksheet.merged_cells:
        top_left_cell = ''
        for item in interim_worksheet.merged_cells.ranges:
            top_left_cell = item.coord.split(':')[0]
        finals_worksheet[cell.coordinate].value = interim_worksheet[top_left_cell].value
else:
```

With the above code example if the cells D6 and D7 were merged then `top_left_cell` will be `'D6'`.

But as noted in the comment with the main loop;

```
for row in interim_worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=6, max_row=200, min_col=4, max_col=7):
    for cell in row:
```

you will be trying to process non existent cells. Using the example of cells D6 and D7 being merged, on the first row loop the cells will be `D6, E6, F6` etc, then on the second loop the first cell will be the non existant `D7` so at that point the code needs to determine that or it will break again.

The same issue can also occur in the opposite way. If D7 is a valid cell in the interim sheet but merged on the Final sheet (and top left is 'D6') then the line

```
finals_worksheet[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
```

would also fail since you cannot write to it in the Finals sheet. It would return the error;

```
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only
```

Comment: Hm,, im still weirdly enough getting a trace (https://pastebin.com/XCzhpY71), but honestly your help gets me on the right track and I am going to try some new way of working around it. +1 forsure for the help

Comment: Your coding idea for the Openpyxl is fine. You should just need to determine for each cell if it is in a merged cell and if so if its the top left which you are doing then copy it. If it isn't, move on to the next cell. Then the only question is if the cell merging is the same on both sheets, if it is then there should be no attempts to copy a non top left cell to a non top left cell. If it isn't then either add the same merge if that's what you want or determine where it should be copied on finals.

Comment: My god, I think I did it. You are the best! Thanks so much! Also, no worries if you dont have time but it deleted images on all pages - was wondering if that was always gonna happen with openpyxl? thanks!

Comment: Yes, Openpyxl does not read every item as noted in the docs **openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so shapes will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name.** so this means images too unfortunately. The best option is to re-add them as part of your code, well unless re-adding them manually is trivial.

Comment: Ah man, that stinks. I guess I could try to readd them? I didnt know you could do that, since they are typically free - floating. Would I assign the photos so a cell to readd them?

Comment: Yes you can anchor to a cell see https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html?highlight=images

Comment: Interesting, so would I just make sure to do something like this?

        my_png = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(png_loc)
        ws.add_image(my_png, 'B3')
        wb.save('logo.xlsx')

and make sure to save before the end of the script? or to save in the beginning? Ill have to figure out how to do it in every worksheet too

Comment: Make sure you import `openpyxl.drawing.image` then code looks good bearing in mind the workbook and worksheet  are 'finals_workbook' and 'finals_worksheet'. You want to add image(s) to the sheet when its active so within the file loop. On the subject of saving, you should only ever need to save once at the very end so the code as you've shown saving on every file is unnecessary. Move `finals_workbook.save(finals_file_path)` to top level indent so it gets executed last. The two lines `interim_workbook.close()` and
`finals_workbook.close()` will do nothing given the method the files were open.